# Can "davon" be separated into "da + von"?

Tags: preposition, sentence-structure, pronominal-adverb

Please consider the following sentences:

> Da kann sich Rio noch eine Scheibe von abschneiden.

> Da sollen sich die Mitteldeutschen mal ne Scheibe von abschneiden."

Shouldn't it be "*davon*"? I mean:

> Davon kann sich Rio noch eine Scheibe abschneiden.

Or are both versions correct?

And does the first usage apply to other da-compounds like "*damit, darunter, dadurch...*"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separating "*davon*" into "*da*" ... "*von*" does not conform to standard German, but it is common in Northern Germany in colloquial language. (I'm not sure about other regions.)

So, the correct (standard German) version is:

> Davon kann sich Rio noch eine Scheibe abschneiden.

And in some regions you might often hear the separated version:

> Da kann sich Rio noch eine Scheibe von abschneiden.

Your second example

> Da sollen sich die Mitteldeutschen mal ne Scheibe von abschneiden.

shows more signs of colloquial language "... *mal ne* Scheibe ... abschneiden"

A standard German version would be

> Davon sollen sich die Mitteldeutschen (ein)mal eine Scheibe abschneiden.

---

I know that this is also applies for "*dafür*".

In Northern Germany you may hear "*Da nich für*" as a response to "*Danke*" or "*Dankeschön*". The response means "Don't thank me for this.", and the standard German form would be "*nicht dafür*", but it is not used as much in the same context.

---

Examples for the other words in your question don't come to my mind, so the separation may not be possible for these. (I'm not sure.)

Answer (score 1):

The quoted sentences are very colloquial. They are certainly not correct in written German, but you may hear them spoken in some regions of Germany. If you find them in a written text they are most probably referring to that spoken usage.